# redraw tileset based map after clearrect

Tags: javascript

I have a weird issue with the `clearrect()` function of js. My app basically excist out of 2 functions where the 1 `drawMap()` renders the map out of an array called `mapArray`. And the function updateGame which updates the current location of the player and renders it.

I have put these together in a very simple game loop system. And call `clearrect()` every frame to remove the old position of the player object.

Now the weird thing is that all this works for the player object. It get removed and drawn again every frame on his new position.

Meanwhile the map only gets drawn on the very first frame (when the player isn't even drawn yet because the main loop hasn't started yet) and doesn't get redrawn after the first `clearrect()` has been called.

My map creation:

```
var mapArray = [
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
];

var grass = new Image();
var dirt = new Image();

grass.src = 'grass.png';
dirt.src = 'dirt.png';

var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;
function drawMap() {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {
            if (mapArray[i][j] == 0){
                ctx.drawImage(grass, posX, posY, 64, 64);
            }
            if (mapArray[i][j] == 1) {
                ctx.drawImage(dirt, posX, posY, 64, 64);
            }
            posX += 64;
        }
        posX = 0;
        posY += 64;
    }
}
```

my player creation:

```
var playerImg = new Image();

var player = {
    speed: 1, // movement in pixels per second
    x: 10,
    y: 200
};

playerImg.src = 'player.png';

function updateGame(){
    //waarom moet dit hier vragen
    if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up      
        player.y -= player.speed;
    }

    ctx.drawImage(playerImg, player.x, player.y);
}
```

and the main game loop

```
var ONE_FRAME_TIME = 1000 / 60 ;
var mainloop = function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 640);
    updateGame();
    drawMap();
};
setInterval(mainloop, ONE_FRAME_TIME);
```

The only thing I can think about is that the map creation takes to long. But when I set the fps to 1 a second it still doesn't show up.

Hope anyone know how to solve this problem?

(Note that I know the code is inefficient, its just for learning/testing purpose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing only the first *drawMap* because your *posY* variable is never reset to 0. If your canvas is just as big to draw the map (in your case 640 x 256) then you are actually drawing outside of the canvas after the first *drawMap*.

Try this:

```
function drawMap() {
    posY = 0;

    // The rest is the same
}
```